# Al mover una imagen, se me mueven las demás

Tags: html

La verdad que recurrí a este medio ya que esto me tiene agotado, comencé hace poco con CSS Y HTML, y quisiera saber por qué al mover una imagen de lugar, se mueven también el resto de imágenes. Además, cuando cambio el Width y Height de la imagen .SirLee, no hay ningún cambio en el tamaño. El problema es ese, al mover una imagen se me mueven otras también, como si estuvieran enlazadas o conectadas, pero no es así ya que cada imagen se encuentra en un div con una clase independiente. Bueno, ojalá me puedan ayudar. ¡Saludos!

```css
body {
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579548122080-c35fd6820ecb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80);
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
}

h1 { 
 animation: infinite resplandorAnimation 2s;
 font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;  
 font-size: 80px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 text-shadow: 0 0 15px white, 0.1em 0.4em 30px black;
}

.border-box {    
 width: 15%;
 height: 10px;
 font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 0.2em 0.3em 8px black; 
 margin-left: 635px;
 margin-top: -60px; 
 background: #f7f5f5;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 15px;
 border-left:9px solid #ff0080;
 border-top-left-radius: 8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:8px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;"}
}

h2 {
 font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;  
 font-size: 20px;  
 color: black;
 text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 2.5px white, 0.1em 0.2em 7px black;  
 margin-left: 650px;
 margin-top: -32px;
}

.Biography {
 color: white; 
 font-size: 18px;
 position: relative; 
 top: 60px;
 left: 1161px; 
 text-align: center;  
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.Palito {
 font-size: 18px; 
 position: relative;
 top: -271px;
 left: 770px;
 color: black;
 animation-name: parpadeo;
 animation-duration: 1s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

.sirLee{ 
 position: relative;
 left: 1150px;
 top: -300px;  
 width: 150px;
 height:1700px;  
}

img {
 max-width: 150%;
 max-height: 150%;
}

.Lee2 {
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 left: -500px;
}

.LabInternet {
 height: 280px;
 width: 250px;
 position: relative;
 top: -300px;
 left: -500px;
}

@keyframes parpadeo {  
  0% { opacity: 1.0; }
   50% { opacity: 0.0; }
  100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}

@keyframes resplandorAnimation {
  0%,100%{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px;
  }
  50%{
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Tim Berners Lee</h1>
<div class="border-box"></div>
<h2>El padre de la web</h2>
<p class=Biography >TIMOTHY "TIM" JOHN BERNERS-LEE (LONDON, UNITED KINGDOM, JUNE 8, 1955), IS A BRITISH COMPUTER SCIENTIST, KNOWN FOR BEING THE FATHER OF THE WORLD WIDE WEB. ESTABLISHED THE FIRST COMMUNICATION BETWEEN A CLIENT AND A SERVER USING THE HTTP PROTOCOL IN DECEMBER 1990.
</p>

<p class=Palito >| </p>


<style>
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?    family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');
</style>

<div class="sirLee"> <img src="https://www.pnglib.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sir-tim-berners-lee-portrait_5e2f0c144f8ca.png" </ </div>
  

<div class="Lee2"> <img src="  https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/TBL-CERN-Tubes.jpg" </ </div>

<div class="LabInternet"> <img src="https://inteng-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/img/iea/Lg6EPmbaGN/sizes/arpanet_resize_md.jpg" /> </div>

  
  <p class="PunteroT" >|</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes algunos detalles en tu código que podrían ser los causantes.

1. Las etiquetas  dentro de .sirLee y .Lee2, no están debidamente cerradas, terminan en `</`, esto genera que las imágenes no se encuentren en los contenedores que esperas.

```
<div class="sirLee">
  <!-- <img src="https://www.pnglib.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sir-tim-berners-lee-portrait_5e2f0c144f8ca.png" </ -->
  <img src="https://www.pnglib.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/sir-tim-berners-lee-portrait_5e2f0c144f8ca.png" />
</div>
<div class="Lee2">
  <!-- <img src="  https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/TBL-CERN-Tubes.jpg" </ -->
  <img src="https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/TBL-CERN-Tubes.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="LabInternet">
  <img src="https://inteng-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/img/iea/Lg6EPmbaGN/sizes/arpanet_resize_md.jpg" />
</div>
```

2. Al corregir el cierre, las imágenes contenidas en .Lee2 y .LabInternet no serán visibles por los valores negativos en left y top left respectivamente. Las imágenes aparecerán una debajo de la otra, pero a partir de aquí podrás reubicarlas de manera independiente.

```
.Lee2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  /* left: -500px; */
  left: 500px;
}

.LabInternet {
  height: 280px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  /*
  top: -300px;
  left: -500px;
  */
  top: 300px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

> cuando cambio el Width y height de la imagen .SirLee, no hay ningún cambio en el tamaño

3. La etiqueta `<img />` tiene [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) y [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height), pero esto sólo limita el crecimiento máximo del contenedor sobreescribiendo el width y height respectivamente, pero no especifica sus valores iniciales. Dado que la imagen dentro de .SirLee es pequeña, no verás el mismo resultado que con .Lee2 o .LabInternet. En este caso, puedes indicar que la imagen ocupará en ancho y alto el 100% del contenedor, y modificar el alto de .SirLee, de este modo todas las imágenes se adaptarán al tamaño de su contenedor.

```
.sirLee { 
  position: relative;
  left: 1150px;
  top: -300px;  
  width: 150px;
  /* height:1700px; */
  height: 150px;
}

img {
  max-width: 150%;
  max-height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```